# Notation $E[t^X]$ where $X$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a quick question which occured in the context of probability-generating functions but maybe the issue is more basic. For a random variable $X$, the probability-generating function is given as
$$m_X(t) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k) t^k = E[t^X]$$

I don't understand the last expression $E[t^X]$. Is this a notation which is only used in this context or something more general? If the latter, what's the logic behing it?

Comment: It's just notation.It is used more generally: $E(f(X))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k)f(k)$. In this case, $f(k)=t^k$.

Comment: $X$ is a random variable, then any (measurable ...) function of $X$, say $f(X)$ is also a random variable. Since $t^x$ is a function (when domain have been defined ...) so $t^X$ is a random variable, so $E [t^X]$ has its usual meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an example, suppose $X$ were discrete, with two possible values $1$ and $2$, weighted as $P(X=1)=0.75$ and $P(X=2)=0.25$.

Now fix $t$ for a second. Say, $t=3$. What can $t^X$ be? Either $3^1$, $75\%$ of the time, or $3^2$, $25\%$ of the time.

So the expected value of $3^X$ is the weighted average of $3$ and $9$, which is $3\cdot0.75+9\cdot0.25=4.5$.

Imagine doing this for all $t$, not just $t=3$. Then $\operatorname{E}(t^X)$ is different for each $t$. And then also, extend the concept from the discrete probability model to the continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable over $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

Then (either taken as a definition or a theorem), $$E[g(X)] = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}g(x)\Pr\left(X = x\right)\text{.}$$

Comment: Thank you! I chose the other answer but this is also really helpful!